# SSLHandshakeException on server restart

Tags: liferay-6

I am getting the following exception after restarting server.
I have not installed SSL on tomcat,
I have installed it on apache and redirecting to tomcat from apache then added following properties in `portal-ext.properties`.

```
web.server.protocol=https

redirect.url.domains.allowed=*.xyz.com
```

following are the logs

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address xx.xxx.xxx.xx found
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1914)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1472)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:213)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1033)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1342)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1353)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1302)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.apache.jsp.get_005forganization_005fimg_jsp._jspService(get_005forganization_005fimg_jsp.java:93)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.include(IncludeTag.java:295)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doInclude(IncludeTag.java:192)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:83)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TagTransformModel$TagWriter.endEvaluation(TagTransformModel.java:430)        
        at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
        at com.liferay.portal.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemplate.processTemplate(FreeMarkerTemplate.java:122)
        at com.liferay.portal.template.AbstractTemplate.processTemplate(AbstractTemplate.java:108)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.doIncludeFTL(ThemeUtil.java:344)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.doDispatch(ThemeUtil.java:169)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.includeFTL(ThemeUtil.java:113)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.include(ThemeUtil.java:96)
        at com.liferay.taglib.theme.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:34)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspx_meth_liferay_002dtheme_005finclude_005f1(portal_jsp.java:572)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspService(portal_jsp.java:515)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.StrutsUtil.forward(StrutsUtil.java:78)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:546)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:523)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:359)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:243)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter.processFilter(CacheFilter.java:408)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:70)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:263)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:226)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.monorail.url.filter.URLFilter.doFilter(URLFilter.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor961.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy853.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address xx.xxx.xxx.xx found
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:167)
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:203)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1454)
        ... 184 more
```

Answer (score 0):

web.server.protocol=https

redirect.url.domains.allowed=*.xyz.com

I don't think this would be needed for redirection

You have to only mention ajp:// proxy pass at Apache side

Comment: Explain more on why this is an answer.

Comment: @InfectedDrake Because he has configured https in apache side not in liferay side